# How to retrieve value from custom payment method in onepage checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, magento-1

I have built a new payment method and I added a custom field in the onepage checkout payment select step.

When you select my payment method, you have a choice to select installments. I need to access that value (number of installments) and post it via form to the payment service page.

How can I retrieve that value?

Comment: Please add some code or screenshots do describe what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

#### Question, how I understand it

I hope I understand the question correct. You have a payment method and the problem, that in onepage checkout a field is added inside the `<dd>` and when the method is selected, the field is shown, but the value is not transfered to the controller.

#### Answer

The problem is, that the "feeled" submit of the form is no submit. It is a call to `Payment.save()`, defined here: `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js:770`

Theoretically everything inside of `<form action="" id="co-payment-form">` should be transfered: `parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)`, (line 782)

So on this side everything should be done automatically. Now you can just access your parameter with the name as always: `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('YOUR_NAME')`.

This can be done inside a observer, for example while listening to `sales_quote_payment_import_data_before` or `sales_order_payment_save_before`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. And, where is the observer `sales_order_payment_save_before`?